# How to calculate percentage of specific pod CPU usage on each node?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

I have a Fluentd daemonset on the k8s cluster with 3 nodes. I would like to get a value which represents percentage which gives me an information on how much CPU (in %) on each node, fluentd pod occupies at this moment.

What would be the way to do it in Prometheus?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to use the `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` query in Prometheus.

Like so:

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{}[5m])) by (container_name)
```

This will return the CPU usage of all the pods `by` container name in the system.

---

You can apply some filters as well to fine grain the output. For example:

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name=~"fluentd.*"}[5m])) by (container_name)
```

The above query will return the CPU usage with pods that matches containers name starting with `fluentd`

---

You can divide the usage of those pods by the total cpu cores of your cluster to find out the usage in percentage, like so:

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name=~"fluentd.*"}[5m])) / sum (machine_cpu_cores{}) * 100
```

---

Finally, in order to get percentage of total cpu cores usage on specific node for specific container_name, you would add additional filter: instance="INSTANCE_NAME":

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name=~"fluentd.*", instance="INSTANCE_NAME"}[5m])) / sum (machine_cpu_cores{}) * 100
```

*N.B: Depending on K8S version, the fields returned by the `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` query may vary. On some system, the name of the containers is represented by the `container_name` field, wheres on some system it is `container`.*

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return per-node CPU usage in percentage for pods with container name, which starts from `fluentd`:

```
100 * (
  sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container=~"fluentd.*"}[5m])) by (node)
    / on (node)
  kube_node_status_capacity{resource="cpu"}
)
```

The `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` metric is exported by [cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/) - see [these docs](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/storage/prometheus.md).

The `kube_node_status_capacity` metric is exported by [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics). See [these docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/3193891ee442ee9552745d054c8d0140295431f3/docs/node-metrics.md).

Comment: it returns Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 2:12: parse error: expected type range vector in call to function "rate", got instant vector